# Push notifications not working on White-Label Rocket Chat App

Tags: android, firebase, chat, rocket.chat

So I am compiling Rocket Chat to use my own Firebase server so I can server notifications without worrying about hitting the notification limit. [I've followed the steps here](https://developer.rocket.chat/mobile-app/mobile-app-white-labelling/android-app-white-labelling) and gotten a working Experimental version of the app on Android, but I can't seem to get the notifications to work. Checking Firebase shows no users of my app, though sometimes it will register a single user but that's it. I've got to be missing something simple, but I can't figure out what. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

If you need any more information just let me know.\

UPDATE: I can send test notifications from Firebase and they show up on the device, however they are not marked as read in Firebase when clicked. It seems as if notifications work from Firebase, but it has no way to communicate back to Firebase.

**FINAL UPDATE:** It turns out that Rocket Chat server needs the legacy version of the FCM keys. By replacing the existing google-services.json file with the one provided by Firebase and following the instructions to get the legacy keys caused notifications to work. Hopefully someone else can benefit from this insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FINAL UPDATE: It turns out that Rocket Chat server needs the legacy version of the FCM keys. By replacing the existing google-services.json file with the one provided by Firebase and following the instructions to get the legacy keys caused notifications to work. Hopefully someone else can benefit from this insight.